# How to create in python3 a list of repeated lists without the new list being affected by a change in the original small list?

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

```
init = [[0,1],[10,11]]
constr1 = [init for _ in range(5)]
constr2 = init * 5
```

First question, why the above 2 constructed lists do not give the same result and they are instead

```
constr1 
[[[0, 1], [10, 11]],
[[0, 1], [10, 11]],
[[0, 1], [10, 11]],
[[0, 1], [10, 11]],
[[0, 1], [10, 11]]]

constr2
[[0, 1], [10, 11],
[0, 1], [10, 11],
[0, 1], [10, 11],
[0, 1], [10, 11],
[0, 1], [10, 11]]
```

And the other question is if I edit the initial list

```
init[0][1]=2
```

then we can see that both constr1 and constr2 have been affected and they are

```
[[[0, 2], [10, 11]],
[[0, 2], [10, 11]],
[[0, 2], [10, 11]],
[[0, 2], [10, 11]],
[[0, 2], [10, 11]]]
```

and

```
[[0, 2], [10, 11],
[0, 2], [10, 11],
[0, 2], [10, 11],
[0, 2], [10, 11],
[0, 2], [10, 11]]
```

So what is the way to get a constructed list (by repetition of list init) and the constr list NOT being affected by any subsequent changes in the init list? NOTE I also tried the line (after clearing all my variables by restarting my python shell)

```
constr1 = [init[:] for _ in range(5)]
```

and still it is affected by a change in init[0][1]

Answer (score 1):

OK , after finding the 
[Untie nested lists created by repetition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49376254/untie-nested-lists-created-by-repetition)
I tried this and it worked

```
init = [[0,1],[10,11]]
from copy import deepcopy
constr1 = [deepcopy(init) for _ in range(5)]
```

Now a change in

```
init[0][1] = 2
```

does not affect the

```
constr1
[[[0, 1], [10, 11]],
 [[0, 1], [10, 11]],
 [[0, 1], [10, 11]],
 [[0, 1], [10, 11]],
 [[0, 1], [10, 11]]]
```

Comment: That was what I was going to suggest.